# Replacing Google Cloud Printing

Tags: networking, printing, cloud

I often use Google's Cloud Print (GCP). In fact, I have family in another continent that prints some non-confidential stuff on my local printer running on raspberry OS / raspbian. The system is good for this type of use but, now that Google (as usually) is going to deprecate / eliminate GCP by the end of 2020, I'm left wondering what can replace GCP as an equally functional and free alternative?

First I thought that maybe ddns could be used to redirect print services, but since (i believe) GCP is a kind of print-job polling service and that ddns wasn't design for this kind of service, then it cannot work like this. So...

1. Is there any alternative (free and equally functional) to Google Cloud Printing? If so, what has to be installed, (server side and client side)? Does it run also in arm/arm64/android?
2. Is there any local alternative (other than expose the server to the internet since I believe cups run IPP protocol)?
3. But even if we expose CUPS to the internet, where can I find an easy comprehensive tutorial to configure IPP, the server, and the routers for this to work?

Sorry for my lousy English.
Thank you

Comment: your English is very good ... a lot better than some of the native speakers

Answer (score 1):

You could try [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/). It is free software and you even have a prebuilt [image for the Rasbperry Pi](https://ownyourbits.com/nextcloudpi/).

[This tutorial](https://raspberrytips.com/install-nextcloud-raspberry-pi/) takes you there (easy way and not so easy, also specific for Raspberry Pi).

Here is some documentation about the [printing application](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/printer) (I have not tried it).

Comment: I didn't know NextCloud has a print feature, however I do not know if this can be used as an adequate replacement for GCP, at least from the point of view of my GCP usage experience. It looks more like a way to print files already hosted in the NextCloud system, but maybe I'm wrong. Thank You for the info.